# B2B access in multi tenant application

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, b2b

I have succesfully setup a multi tenant application.
For now, I am able to authenticate the user and use tokens to access other resources. (Microsoft Graph & Microsoft AD Graph)

Now I want to get B2B working.
Current flow: 
- User signs in
- AuthorizationCodeReceived gets the acquires the token (via $commonAuthority endpoint)
- When requesting a token for the Ad Graph, I am using the $tenantAuthority

This works perfectly when $tenantAuthority is the same tenant authority as the one where the account was created in.

However, if I login with another user (from another tenant, given trust to the actual tenant) and use $tenantAuthority = trusted authority, then I always the following error: 
Failed the refresh token:
AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID

If I change $tenantAuthority to the 'source' tenant authority where the user was created in, everything works fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update: Code sample**

App has two tenants (tenantA en tenantB) and I will use a user from tenantB with tenantA given a trust to this user.

```
AuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
                    {
                        TenantContext.TenantId = "someguid";
                        var tenantId =
                            TenantContext.TenantId;

                        // get token cache via func, because the userid is only known at runtime
                        var getTokenCache = container.Resolve<Func<string, TokenCache>>();
                        var userId = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.ObjectIdentifier).Value;
                        var tokenCache = getTokenCache(userId);
                        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext($"{configuration.Authority}",
                            tokenCache);

                        await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                            context.Code,
                            new Uri(context.Request.Uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)),
                            new ClientCredential(configuration.ClientId, configuration.ClientSecret),
                            configuration.GraphResourceId);
                    }
```

This code works perfectly. Login in with a user from both tenants works perfectly.

But when I need the Graph Service Client or ActiveDirectoryClient, I need to obtain access tokens to been able to address an api for a certain tenant. I retrieve the access tokens like this:

```
public IGraphServiceClient CreateGraphServiceClient()
    {
        var client = new GraphServiceClient(
            new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                async requestMessage =>
                {
                    Logger.Debug("Retrieving authentication token to use in Microsoft Graph.");

                    string token;
                    var currentUserHomeTenantId = TenantContext.TenantId;
                    var currentUserObjectId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.ObjectIdentifier).Value;
                    var authenticationContext =
                        new AuthenticationContext($"{_configuration.TenantAuthorityPrefix}{currentUserHomeTenantId}",
                            _tokenCacheFactoryMethod(currentUserObjectId));
                    var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(_configuration.ClientId, _configuration.ClientSecret);

                    try
                    {
                        token = await GetTokenSilently(authenticationContext, _configuration.GraphResourceId, currentUserObjectId);
                    }
                    catch (AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException e)
                    {
                        Logger.Error("Failed to retrieve authentication token silently, trying to refresh the token.", e);
                        var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(_configuration.GraphResourceId, clientCredential);
                        token = result.AccessToken;
                    }

                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(AuthenticationHeaderKeys.Bearer, token);
                }));

        return client;
    }


    public IActiveDirectoryClient CreateAdClient()
    {
        var currentUserHomeTenantId = TenantContext.TenantId;
        var currentUserObjectId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.ObjectIdentifier).Value;
        var graphServiceUrl = $"{_configuration.AdGraphResourceId}/{currentUserHomeTenantId}";
        var tokenCache = _tokenCacheFactoryMethod(currentUserObjectId);

        var client = new ActiveDirectoryClient(new Uri(graphServiceUrl),
            () => GetTokenSilently(
                new AuthenticationContext(
                    $"{_configuration.TenantAuthorityPrefix}{ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.TenantId).Value}", tokenCache
                ),
                _configuration.AdGraphResourceId, currentUserObjectId
            ));

        return client;
    }
```

When I do a request with one of the two client SDK's, I got the following error:
Failed the refresh token: AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID.

Comment: Did you see the consent page when you login using the accounts from other tenant? If not would you mind share the piece of code how about login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the catch method when retrieving the Token did the trick:

```
if(e.ErrorCode == "failed_to_acquire_token_silently")
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(authenticationContext.GetAuthorizationRequestUrlAsync(resourceId, _configuration.ClientId, new Uri(currentUrl),
                        new UserIdentifier(currentUserId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId), string.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you mention that so: in a B2B collaboration you've to invite user from other tenant first. The steps are like that:

- invite and authorize a set of external users by uploading a comma-separated values - CSV file
- Invitation will be send to external users.
- The invited user will either sign in to an existing work account with Microsoft (managed in Azure AD), or get a new work account in Azure AD.
- After signed in, user will be redirected to the app that was shared with them

That works perfectly in my case.

Regarding some problems which I've detect:

**Trailing "/" at the end of the active directory resource** - try to remove it as this may cause problems. Bellow you will find some code to get authentication headers:

```
string aadTenant = WebServiceClientConfiguration.Settings.ActiveDirectoryTenant;
string clientAppId = WebServiceClientConfiguration.Settings.ClientAppId;
string clientKey = WebServiceClientConfiguration.Settings.ClientKey;
string aadResource = WebServiceClientConfiguration.Settings.ActiveDirectoryResource;

AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadTenant);
ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientAppId, clientKey);
UserPasswordCredential upc = new UserPasswordCredential(WebServiceClientConfiguration.Settings.UserName, WebServiceClientConfiguration.Settings.Password);

AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(aadResource, clientAppId, upc);

return authenticationResult.CreateAuthorizationHeader();
```

**Applications provisioned in Azure AD are not enabled to use the OAuth2 implicit grant by default. You need to explicitly opt in** - more details can be found here: [Azure AD OAuth2 implicit grant](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2015-4-Azure_AD_OAuth2_implicit_grant.aspx)

Comment: Just a thought, can I not invoke this adding and inviting operation using Graph API.??

Comment: Adding and inviting an user are separate things. This is inviting an user and it is still in preview. https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/invitation - Rest API